# Slow Query Occurs During MariaDB Multiple Concurrent Client Bulk Insert

Tags: mariadb, database-performance

I have a problem to multiple  concurrent client   bulk insert occur  Slow Query.
Can this problem be solved by mariadb tuning?

Comment: Show the code and timing results by editing your question.

Comment: Thank you for reply , I found the reason that is the  Hardware Problem. So I  Change the hardware and than  problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Glad your problem is solved.